# persisting problem installing plugins for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I ve been trying to install plugins from github to my RoR app for a while without success.
here is what i tried on my cmd (cmd using ruby, i have bitnami stack) in the root dir of the app:

ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git

ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git/

i keep getting:

Plugin not found ["git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git"]

i have msysgit installed and github account set with my public key, what do i need to do in msysgit to get this to work?

trying

script/plugin install git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git

or
./script/plugin install git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git

in msys.bat (not sure if i should type the command in the ruby cmd or the msysgit bash) in the app root dir gives me this:

/usr/bin/env: ruby: no such file or directory

i ve also tried replacing: stream.reopen(RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ ? 'NUL:' : '/dev/null') 
with: stream.reopen('NUL:') 
in: \lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\activesupport-2.3.5\lib\active_support\core_ext\kernel\reporting.rb

i am a complete noob so i might be missing something very basic,
i hope someone will help cuz i ve been stuck with this for a whole day
which is not good at all for my deadline.

btw, i am using rails 2.3.5 with ruby 1.8.7 on winxp, bitnami stack.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git/
```

—Including the trailing slash. I'd found this suggestion in this [article](http://jamie.ideasasylum.com/2008/08/installing-rails-plugins-with-git-on-windows/), especially the comments seem to contain plenty of interesting information.

Comment: Even using the http link instead? I know that doesn't solve your problem, but you could always install the plugin manually…

Comment: yeah it s weird that even using http and trailing "/" didn t work.

Answer (score 0):

finally it looks like it worked doing this:
in vendor/plugins

```
git clone git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git
```

i don t know if it ll have bad effects, i ll keep you updated.
(the solution was posted by Jhonson [in here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28908))

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:
Just download the zip file from github, extract it to a folder and copy that to your vendors/plugins folder.